# App Store "open" vs. "installed"

Tags: mac-appstore

Setting up a new MacBook Pro.  In App Store, on Purchased tab, selected most of the apps I had bought (or got free) on the old one.

When they finish downloading, the button changes to "installed" for some of them, and "open" for others.

Why?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I've had a lot of problems with the app store button labels being buggy (many OSs, four different computer models). Have you tried quitting and reopening the App Store app?

Comment: No.  At the moment, it's installing Sierra.  Apple sold it to me with 10.11.6

Comment: Even better, install macOS Sierra and then try reopening the App Store. Let us know if the app store button labels change to "installed".

Comment: Came you give some examples of apps that read 'Installed' vs. apps that read 'Open'? I'm using Sierra and I just tested the App Store with 10 apps I installed either on my work MacPro, or on my laptop, but not on my home iMac. Some were third party, two were Apple apps. All read 'Installed', and the button is greyed out. Other apps, already installed, read 'Open'.

Comment: On a "new" Mac, only the stock apps are there.  So logging in to the app store shows all the ones that are not, with buttons saying "install."  After selecting all of those, and letting the process finish, some say "open" and some "installed."  But I won't be able to take another look at it for several days.  I could have migrated them from the old Mac but some of them were removed by the "genius" trying to help me resolve an issue in the old one.  Hence trying a fresh re-install on the new mac.  (Bought because of that issue.)